# Android layout: how to get button width across remaining "columns" in table row?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

I've got a couple of table rows in a table layout. The last row got a button which I would like to stretch out to right side (i.e. fill the remaining space on right side in the row). When I try to stretch this button, other buttons in the row above also get stretched, which I don't want to happen. See image link for what I'm trying to achieve.  The green button is supposed to go over "three columns".

Any tip on how I can do this?

[image: Image for table row]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may try something like this

```
<TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:weightSum="100" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button android:text="Button" android:layout_weight="20"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
        <Button android:text="Button" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="20" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
        <Button android:text="Button" android:layout_weight="40"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
    </TableRow>
```

Comment: Worked nicely with weightsum! Thanks mate.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to set the `layoutSpan` property for your button and row. In your image the `layoutSpan` should pe set to 3..

**EDIT:**

Indeed, you can't set `layoutSpan` for row but you can for `Button` instead.. in my application this works.

Good luck!

Comment: I don't thing this property is available for button or row..?

Comment: Thanks, so you mean I set like this for the green button? <Button android:layoutSpan="3" [other properties]/>?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply have 2 tables in a row with only one of them having tablestretch.

Or go look at: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html#attr_android:stretchColumns